# How to resolve the error occurring in FB-Prophet ? pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed

Tags: python, pip, facebook-prophet, python-holidays

An error is occuring in the FB prophet model

```
Installing collected packages: holidays
  Attempting uninstall: holidays
    Found existing installation: holidays 0.21.13
    Uninstalling holidays-0.21.13:
      Successfully uninstalled holidays-0.21.13
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
neuralprophet 0.6.2 requires holidays<0.22,>=0.21, but you have holidays 0.42 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed holidays-0.42
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [holidays]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are installing your packages at present, but I'll assume that you have a `requirements.txt`. Try specifying these versions:

`requirements.txt`

```
neuralprophet==0.6.2
holidays==0.21.13
```

You don't need to specify a version for `holidays` though since it's installed implicitly by `neuralprophet`. Either way though, `neuralprophet` requires a `0.21.x` version.

If you're not using `requirements.txt` then uninstall your current version of `holidays` and then try installing `neuralprophet` again.

```
pip3 uninstall holidays
pip3 install neuralprophet==0.6.2
```